# Symfony Custom Route loader, loading multiple times, getting exception

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I'm trying to make custom routeloader according to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html

my code looks like this

```
//the routeloader:

//the namespace and use code ....

class FooLoader extends Loader{
  private $loaded = false;
  private $service;

  public function __construct($service){
    $this->service = $service;
  }
  public function load($resource, $type=null){
      if (true === $this->loaded) 
        throw new \RuntimeException('xmlRouteLoader is already loaded');
      //process some routes and make $routeCollection
      $this->loaded = true;
      return $routeCollection;
  }
      public function getResolver()
     {
    // needed, but can be blank, unless you want to load other resources
    // and if you do, using the Loader base class is easier (see below)
     }

    public function setResolver(LoaderResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
    // same as above
    }
    function supports($resource, $type = null){

         return $type === 'xmlmenu';
    }

}
```

---

```
//the service definition
    foo.xml_router:
    class: "%route_loader.class%"
    arguments: [@foo.bar_service] //this service and the injection has been tested and works.
    tags:
        - { name: routing.loader }
```

---

```
//the routing definitions

//routing_dev.yml
_foo: 
  resource: "@FooBarBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

-----------------------------
//FooBarBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
_xml_routes:
  resource: .
  type: xmlmenu
```

---

and when I try to access any route I get the exception:

> RuntimeException: xmlRouteLoader is already loaded

which is the exception I defined if the loader is loaded multiple times.So why does it try to load this loader more than once? and I'm pretty sure I've defined it only there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer was quite simple.it seems like this method only supports one level of imports.I only needed to put the _xml_routes directly under routing_dev.yml, otherwise it somehow winds out in a loop.explanations to why that is are appreciated.